# Coordinates of the edge of a Mobius strip

Tags: matlab, octave, mobius

Here is a Octave/Matlab code for generating a Mobius strip.

```
u = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
v = linspace(-1.0,1.0,100);
[u,v] = meshgrid(u,v);

x = (1+v.*cos(u/2)).*cos(u);
y = (1+v.*cos(u/2)).*sin(u);
z = v.*sin(u/2);

plot3(x,y,z)
```

The output is as follow.
In this, strip, I need the edge coordinates (XYZ). How I can get the XYZ coordinates of the edge?

[image: Mobius strip]

Comment: What are the "edge coordinates"? The first/last column/row of XYZ?

Comment: The Mobius strip has only one ege. I do not know how to extract the edge co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do this using python as follows. See a related post [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208513/generate-xyz-coordinates-of-a-tube-made-of-multiple-rings/208535?noredirect=1#comment404215_208535)

```
bLength=1.6
numPoints=10
radius = bLength*numPoints / (2 * np.pi)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,numPoints,endpoint=False)
dtheta=theta[1]-theta[0]

x0,y0=(radius * np.cos(theta)), (radius * np.sin(theta))
x1,y1=(radius * np.cos(theta+dtheta/2)) , (radius * np.sin(theta+dtheta/2))
cons0=np.ones(x0.shape)*0
cons1=np.ones(x1.shape)*2

np.savetxt('cooRing00.csv',np.c_[x0,y0,cons0],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing01.csv',np.c_[x1,y1,cons1],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plot3(x([1 end],:).',y([1 end],:).',z([1 end],:).', "b")
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks. But, I have to get twisted structure of the ring given here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zquYm.png